# Use a file to search another file and print lines matching a pattern to first file

Tags: python, search

Python noob here. I've been smashing my head trying to do this, tried several Unix tools and I'm convinced that python is the way to go.

I have two files, File1 has headers and numbers like this:

```
>id1
77
>id2
2
>id3
2
>id4
22
...
```

Note that id number is unique, but the number assigned to it may repeat. I have several files like this all with the same number of headers (~500).

File2 has all numbers of File1 and an appended sequence

```
1
ATCGTCATA
2
ATCGTCGTA
...
22
CCCGTCGTA
...
77
ATCGTCATA
...
```

Note that sequence id is unique, as all sequences after it. I have the same amount of files as File1 but the number of sequences within each File2 may vary(~150).

*My desired output is the File1 with the sequence from File2, it is important that File1 maintains original order.*

```
>id1
ATCGTCATA
>id2
ATCGTCGTA
>id3
ATCGTCGTA
>id4
CCCGTCGTA
```

My approach is to extract numbers from File1 and use them as a pattern to match in File2. First I am trying to make this work with only a pair of files. here is what I achieved:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

datafile = 'protein2683.fasta.txt.named'
schemaseqs = 'protein2683.fasta'

with open(datafile, 'r') as f:
    datafile_lines = set([line.strip() for line in f]) #maybe I could use regex to get only lines with number as pattern?
    print (datafile_lines)

outputlist = []

with open(schemaseqs, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        seqs = line.split(',')[0]
        if seqs[1:-1] in datafile_lines:
            outputlist.append(line)

    print (outputlist)
```

This outputs a mix of patterns from File1 and the sequences from File2. Any help is appreciated.

Ps: I am open to modifications in files structure, I tried substituting \n in File2 for "," with no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

datafile = 'protein2683.fasta.txt.named'
schemaseqs = 'protein2683.fasta'
datafile_lines = []
d = {}
prev = None
with open(datafile, 'r') as f:
    i = 0
    for line in f:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            d[line.strip()]=0
            prev = line.strip()
        else:
            d[prev] = line.strip()
        i+=1

new_d = {}
with open(schemaseqs, 'r') as f:
    i=0
    prev = None
    for line in f:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            new_d[line.strip()]=0
            prev = line.strip()
        else:
            new_d[prev] = line.strip()
        i+=1

for key, value in d.items():
    if value in new_d:
        d[key] = new_d[value]

print(d)

with open(datafile,'w') as filee:
    for k,v in d.items():
        filee.writelines(k)
        filee.writelines('\n')
        filee.writelines(v)
        filee.writelines('\n')
```

creating two dictionary would be easy and then map both dictionary values.

Comment: This works flawlessly! I have modified to accept file1 and file2 from command line. Any idea how to implement a loop to run in every pair of file1 and file2 sharing the same pattern in name?

Comment: can you give me an example

Comment: I would like this script to run on a thousand pairs, all datafile files are named .txt and all schemaseqs are named .fasta. For example, we have a pair 555.fasta and 555.txt, then 556, 557.

Comment: use import os,  os.listdir(pathToFolder) to get names of all files stored in pathToFolder. And then loop over list and compare names of file.@Matteoli

Answer (score 0):

Since the files are so neatly organized, I wouldn't use a set to store the lines. Sets don't enforce order, and the order of these lines conveys a lot of information. I also wouldn't use Regex; it's probably overkill for the task of parsing individual lines, but not powerful enough to keep track of which ID corresponds to each gene sequence.

Instead, I would read the files in the opposite order. First, read the file with the gene sequences and build a mapping of IDs to genes. Then read in the first file and replace each id with the corresponding value in that mapping.

If the IDs are a continuous sequence (1, 2, 3... n, n+1), then a list is probably the easiest way to store them. If the file is already in order, you don't even have to pay attention to the ID numbers; you can just skip every other row and append each gene sequence to an array in order. If they aren't continuous, you can use a dictionary with the IDs as keys. I'll use the dictionary approach for this example:

```
id_to_gene_map = {}

with open(file2, 'r') as id_to_gene_file:
    for line_number, line in enumerate(id_to_gene_file, start=1):
        if line_number % 2 == 1:  # Update ID on odd numbered lines, including line 1
            current_id = line
        else:
            id_to_gene_map[current_id] = line  # Map previous line's ID to this line's value

with open(file1, 'r') as input_file, open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    for line in input_file:
        if not line.startswith(">"):  # Keep ">id1" lines unchanged
            line = id_to_gene_map[line]  # Otherwise, replace with the corresponding gene
        output_file.write(line)
```

In this case, the IDs and values both have trailing newlines. You can strip them out, but since you'll want to add them back in for writing the output file, it's probably easiest to leave them alone.

Comment: This looks solid but if flagging a warning:
"with open(datafile, 'r') as input_file, open(output, 'w') as output_file:
NameError: name 'output' is not defined". I do not fully understand what is being done here, is a newfile called output will be created?

Comment: I edited my answer to make it clearer. “Output” would be the name of whatever file you want to write to.